# Are there any efficient algorithms for "flood problem?"

Tags: algorithm, graph, greedy

I have to find out the threshold of rain falls that block traffic.

So, I have to print the threshold of precipitation to block traffics.

ex)

3 3

0 1 2

1 2 3

0 2 6

 output : 3

Are there any good algorithms or keywords for this problem?

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "block traffics"?  Disconnect the network?

Comment: Yes, kinds of. For the Example 1, when rain fall is 3, the city(vertices)-1 is not connected to other nodes. 0->1(disconnected), 1->2(disconnected), otherwise 0->2(connected, because it has 3 more capacity)

Comment: Look at how minimum spanning tree algorithms work, they could help you determine when the graph becomes disconnected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find a spanning tree with maximum total flood capacity.  The smallest edge capacity in that tree is the threshold at which the network would become disconnected.

The "maximum capacity" tree is the same as the minimum weight spanning tree with edge weights equal to negative capacity, so you can find this tree using Kruskal's or Prim's algorithm.

Kruskal's algorithm obviously does exactly what you want -- processes the edges in order of descending capacity until the network is connected: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm

The surprising thing, if you're not familiar with the disjoint set data structure, is that it's very fast.

Any algorithm for finding a minimum spanning tree will do the same job, too, but it's a little work to prove that.

Comment: But, How can I implemented it to directed weight graph? As far as I know, spanning tree is worked on indirect graph..,

Comment: The roads are all one-way?

Comment: Well, basically, nothing is guaranteed. The road is directed, but bi-direction is also possible with different weight.

Comment: You will need a different algorithm, then, and it again becomes hard to tell what you want.  In example 1, when rainfall is 2, you can no longer get to v1 through any directed edges, and I don't know why that wouldn't count as traffic being blocked.